# Hacking an AC power unit with a transformer

Tags: power-supply, transformer, safety

I have some [mini speakers](http://support.creative.com/kb/ShowArticle.aspx?sid=66545) whose power pack has died.  I can't find any suitable looking replacement power unit as the spec is unusual - 12V AC output 2.9A.  Nothing on Amazon or eBay looks suitable.

Sounds like it's essentially a step-down transformer I need.  Lots of these available - e.g. [this 220-12V 30W example](http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/220V-50Hz-Double-Phase-EI-Core-Power-Transformer-12V-30W-Output-w-Cable-/191683511122).  But would such a unit be theoretically sound or would it need any additional elements to be safe, other than a 3A fuse?

Comment: That should work, I don't see any reason why not.

Comment: I've accepted the Creative answer, but if for general benefit anyone gives a more relevant explanation of why the transformer method would be ok I'll accept that instead..

Comment: The photo of the Creative device shows that it is marked as an I.T.E. (information technology equipment) power supply and is listed by UL as meeting the applicable USA and Canada requirements. The two squares, box-in-a-box symbol in the upper right means that it meets the "double insulated" requirements. It has an attached cord and plug with a strain relief feature and a sturdy enclosure. I have noticed that consumer items sometimes (perhaps often) have thermal fuses imbedded inside these days. That may be a UL requirement. UK products may have similar safety / idiot-proof requirements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creative make one: -

[image]

And [here](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00A6VFQD4) is the amazon link.

It was top of the search engine list so I don't know what you are doing to have missed it.

Comment: Thanks Andy.  Yes that's what broke.  I don't search Amazon US as the postage costs for this kind of thing are too high (even if 2nd hand sellers will post to us).  Nothing like this in Amazon UK..

Comment: Go to creative and buy one. I think the GigaWorks T20 is compatible - see this link and scroll down: http://support.creative.com/kb/ShowArticle.aspx?sid=6098

Comment: That's the version 2 range - 15V DC in.  But actually you've helped me.  The link gives the `MAG120290BH4` unit code and I've found a replacement on eBay UK.  Cheers.